# Make a flexible screen especially make flexible or automatic shrinkable table width when a side slide bar is clicked by user using angularJs

Tags: angularjs

This is to just get some new and updated components in angularJs that are used currently. I searched all over the net and got confused which ones to use in angularJs. My requirement is to get a flexible screen, which means that when a small slide bar is opened by clicking a button then the table present must shrink or resize itself.

I searched using bootstrap with angularJs. Are there any other new components in angularjs that are very good and best in market.

Any help will be fine and helpful.

Comment: You don't need any component to do that. Only avoid hard-coding the width of your table. And anyway, questions asking to recommend tools or libraries are off-topic here.

Comment: Thank You. Sure I will make sure not to ask any off-topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)
The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

these you can use according to your need